# Is it bad practice to have an empty base class for Viewmodels in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, mvvm

I am designing a (somewhat) simple quiz app for a school project to get comfortable with MVVM.

It has two views- one for the actual quiz portion and one for the results etc. when it is finished.

To navigate between these views I am using a BaseVeiwModel class that is currently empty (only inherits from an ObservableObject class implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged).

This is then the base class for my two viewmodels, in which I have an instance of it set to the Current View, allowing me to switch between them with a method in my first viewmodel.

I want to ask if it's bad practice to have a base viewmodel class that is empty, and if it is what should I do? I did consider just using an ObservableObject instance, as they both inherit from OBservableObject- but I thought that would look less clear and more messy- as my models also inherit from ObservableObject.

EDIT:

So, my BaseViewModel is currently instatiated in my first VeiwModel

```
private BaseVeiwModel _currentVeiw;
public BaseVeiwModel CurrentVeiw
{
    get { return _currentVeiw; }
    set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _currentVeiw, value); }
 }

 //in the constructor:
 CurrentVeiw = this;
```

Then I have a method (which is used as a command by a button currently but will be called inside the QuestionViewModel class) to change the view to my second one:

```
private void ChangeView(object blank)
    {
        CurrentVeiw = new FinishedVeiwModel();
        Console.WriteLine("Button Clicked!");
        Console.WriteLine(CurrentVeiw);
    }
```

My Base class is simply:

```
 public class BaseVeiwModel :ObservableObject
{
    //Completely empty
}
```

Comment: This question would be clearer if you posted some example code.

Comment: What's the purpose of the BaseVeiwModel class? Why don't the view models inherit directly from the ObservableObject class?

Comment: @mm8 I tried to explain this in the post but I don't think I worded it well. They both could inherit directly from ObservableObject (and they used to) but so do my models- so I though it would be messy to have an ObservableObject instance that controls my views. If you think that would be  better, please leave an answer!

Comment: I have already provided an answer. And I don't really know what you mean by "ObservableObject instance that controls my views".

Comment: @mm8 Sorry, I didn't notice that answer. Looking at it, I think I will approve it, it seems the most apt answer for my question and so will help anyone else reading it, even if it not exactly what I needed (because my class hierarchy is a bit irregular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a common base class for all view models is a very common approach.

All MVVM framworks out there like for example MvvmLight, Prism, Caliburn.Micro and RectiveUI include a base class from which your custom view model classes are supposed to inherit.

So this is certainly not a bad practice. You might also provide your own base class that inherits from a library base class.

If the base class is truly empty, i.e. no `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation  or any code at all, you might want to consider using an interface instead but apart from this there is nothing wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not a bad practice. It's a good idea to implement for example `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a base class because otherwise you would have to do it in each of your viewmodels.

I would recommend making your base class `abstract`. Then you can not create an instance of this base class.

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
```

Have a look at [abstract (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

> The `abstract` modifier indicates that the thing being modified has a
>   missing or incomplete implementation. The abstract modifier can be
>   used with classes, methods, properties, indexers, and events. Use the
>   `abstract` modifier in a class declaration to indicate that a class is
>   intended only to be a base class of other classes. Members marked as
>   abstract, or included in an abstract class, must be implemented by
>   classes that derive from the abstract class.

Comment: The question reads to me like he has a completely empty base class, which itself extends another base class (ObservableObject) which implementes INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Owen Pauling Yes this is what I meant. I need to have an instance of the class, as that is my entire point of having one (so I can change which view is being presented). Sorry if there is any confusion.